# How to display a VSTS Build Badge in a README.md file hosted on GitHub?

Tags: github, azure-devops, readme

I have developed a tiny library that I chose to host on `GitHub`. The code is being built by a VSTS build and published as a NuGet package.

I have written a `README.md` file and I am trying to include a Build badge on it, as described in the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/build/ci-build-github?view=vsts&tabs=designer). Consequently, I have added the following line in the MD file and replaced the placeholders accordindly:

```
![Build status](https://{my-organisation}.visualstudio.com/{my-project}/_apis/build/status/{my-build-definition-name}?branch=master)
```

The problem is that the link is not accessible to anyone that is not logged-in on VSTS and I end up with a 'broken' link on my [readme](https://github.com/kzryzstof/NoSuchCompany.Diagnostics) page:

[image]

**Question**

What must be done to make the VSTS Build Badge available to a GitHub repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you must include an authentication token of sorts in order to have at least read-access to the VSTS build from your GitHub page.

Note that [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/build/ci-build-github?view=vsts&tabs=designer) lists also multiple pending issues, including [MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs issue 1499](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/1499):

> Build status badge added to GitHub readme doesn't show up.

So this is still in progress.

On that last issue, it says:

> This is due to public vs. private projects.
>   If you make your project public the image URL will render.
>   There are other potential workarounds we are looking at for the doc.

See "[Change the project visibility, public or private](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/public/make-project-public?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav)".